# Can a square be in the form $2x + 1$, when $x$ is odd?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, square-numbers

I was given this question, and I think I have solved it, but I'm not sure it is correct because this differs from how the answer is given. **What is the most common way to solve this problem?**

Let's suppose there was a square that could be written as $$2x + 1$$ x being odd. Then: $$2x + 1 = S^2$$ and $$2x = (S + 1)(S - 1)$$ and $$x = \left(\frac{S + 1}{2}\right)(S-1)$$ Now, if $x$ is odd, then $S$ must be odd too. So $S + 1$ is even, therefore $$x = N(S - 1)$$ [with] $N$ being a natural number. And since $S - 1$ is also even, we have $$x = NE.$$ A contradiction, as any number multiplied by even must be even, and $x$ is supposed to be odd.

Comment: The squere of an even number is $\equiv 0\pmod 4$, the square of an odd number is $\equiv 1\pmod 8$, your $2x+1$ is $\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry I don't get that. What do you mean?

Comment: Your proof seems right.  @HagenvonEitzen has essentially put a  proof in a more succint and efficient notation. Since you are studying number theory, now is a perhaps a good time to introduce yourself to modular arithmetic .

Comment: Should we use a word like "succint" on an international mathematics forum? Anyway, I didn't know the word. Look it up in Webster's Dictionary. The word doesn't even exist. There is "succinct" though. It means concise.

Comment: @M.Wind This is a mathematics forum, not a spelling bee.

Comment: @HyperLuminal I will be using succulent and succubus a lot !.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is almost correct. After you reach
$$
2x = (S+1)(S-1)
$$
you say that "if $x$ is odd, then $S$ must be odd too", but there is no implication here. Indeed, since $S^2 = 2x+1$ it follows that $S^2$, and thus $S$ is odd, for every $x \in \Bbb{Z}$. In turn, this means that $S+1$ and $S-1$ are even, so by the above equation $4 \mid 2x$, i.e. $2 \mid x$.

---

As already pointed out by others, the standard way to solve this problem is to show that the square of an integer can only be $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$ -- just take the square of $2k$ or $2k+1$, respectively -- and then that $2x + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: What do you mean, "no implication"?

Comment: @HyperLuminal I mean that $S$ is always odd, independently of the value of $x$. It would probably be more correct to say that the implication is trivial, but here I wanted to point out the "fault" in the OP's reasoning.

Answer (score 5):

$2(2k+1)+1=4k+3\equiv 3 \pmod{4},$ but squares can only be $\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$

Answer (score 4):

The most common way to solve this problem is with modular arithmetic: compute the squares modulo $4$ to obtain this periodic sequence: $$0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots$$ If $x$ is odd, then $2x + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, which is an impossible value for a square.

I will show you a way that is slightly more complicated than the common way but is still simple enough almost anyone can follow along: If $y$ is odd, then $(2y)^2 = 4y^2$, while $(2y + 1)^2 = 4y^2 + 4y + 1$. We can rewrite $$4y^2 + 4y + 1 = 2x + 1$$ by setting $x = 2y^2 + 2y$, but clearly this means $x$ is even, not odd as desired.